# Dictionary learning for sparse coding using ADMM

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, coding-theory

I'm trying to formulate an ADMM for performing dictionary learning (for sparse coding) on a set of data.

Let's assume we have a data matrix of $X \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$, a dictionary of $D \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times K}$ and a coefficient matrix of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times N}$, where $K < N$.

For learning the dictionary, I am following the form of:

$\arg\min_{D,A,B} \frac{1}{2}\|X - DA\|^2_F + \lambda \|B\|_1$

$\text{s.t.        } B = A,  \|d_i\|^2_2 <= 1$

The Lagrangian (using scaled form) is:

$\mathcal{L}(D,A,B,U) = \frac{1}{2}\|X - DA\|^2_F + \lambda \|B\|_1 + \frac{\rho}{2} \|B-A+U\|^2_F$

The update expressions are:

$B^* = \mathcal{S}_{\frac{2\lambda}{\rho}}[-A+U]$ (soft thresholding)

$W^* = (D^TD + \rho I)^{-1} (\rho A + D^T X - \rho U)$

$D^* = XW^T(WW^T)^{-1}$

Having implemented this in MATLAB, I am noticing that I am unable to obtain a reasonable solution. The coefficients are suitably sparse, however the data fidelity ($\|X-DA\|^2_F$) is very poor.

What are some strategies for best choosing $\lambda \text{ and } \rho$?

Comment: What's $ d_i $?

Comment: So $ D $ and $ A$ are both variables? This makes the problem non-convex. Are you supposed to use an alternating minimization strategy, minimizing first with respect to $ D$ then with respect to $ A, B $ , and so on?

Comment: I second @littleO's question. Your problem as described here is non-convex. You can't expect much from it as a result, and you certainly cannot guarantee convergence to a global optimum.

Comment: Hmm, ok I see the problem.

In order to solve this with an ADMM, could one do the following -

Make an initial guess of D, use LASSO to solve for A.
Fix A, solve for D.
Repeat until convergence.

Comment: You could do that, yes, but you would not be able to guarantee convergence to a global minimum, and you would need to be careful to choose your step sizes carefully to ensure convergence to a local minimum.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no constraint on the dictionary learning problem (usually there is a constraint on the norm of each column), ADMM reduces to simple alternating minimization method.So if you consider the constraints, I think it reduces to a method such as Method of Optimal Direction (may be with some negligible differences). So I think for the classical form of dictionary learning, there is no advantage to use ADMM instead of a popular method such as K-SVD ( Note that the K-SVD method is also an alternating minimization method). 
Also, It is worth to note that the K-SVD is not also converge to a global optimum but it is good in practice.( the problem of dictionary learning is not a convex problem. It is a bi-convex problem, so there are local minimums!)